# app crashes in review, but not crash in adhoc distribution

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I've tested my app on various devices with iOS 5, 5.1, and 6.0.1, without crashing. I've also successfully tested it with the Xcode debugger, and via ad-hoc distribution on the same devices.

Yet, it's rejected by Apple:

> We found that your app failed to launch on iPad running iOS 6.0.1, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
>
> We encountered the issue when selecting the application on the Home screen - the app displayed a launch image then quit unexpectedly. This may be because iOS 6 uses a watchdog timer for applications; if an application takes too long to complete its initial startup, the operating system terminates the application.
>
> For information about the watchdog timer, please see Technical Q&A: Application does not crash when launched from debugger but crashes when launched by user..
>
> Another possibility could be a missing entitlement. For more information, please see the Technical Note: Resolving "0x800003A", applications not launching and "missing entitlement". For discrete code-level questions, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. Please be sure to:
>
> - include the complete details of your rejection issues
> - prepare any symbolicated crash logs, screenshots, and steps to reproduce the issues for when the DTS engineer follows up.
>
> For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please see Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application Crash Reports.
>
> If you have difficulty reproducing this issue, please try testing the workflow as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/Testing Workflow with Xcode's Archive feature".

I'm not able to reproduce this issue. This is the crash report:

```
    Incident Identifier: 49209743-0352-4073-B20A-FD81F5CE14D0
    CrashReporter Key:   b0da4d2be342a13b58b877b8096c6853088208c2
    Hardware Model:      iPad3,3
    Process:         collapsibleD [490]
    Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/1812EF83-875B-49CD-9B97-46878ED60F8E/collapsibleD.app/collapsibleD
    Identifier:      collapsibleD
    Version:         ??? (???)
    Code Type:       ARM (Native)
    Parent Process:  launchd [1]
    
    Date/Time:       2012-12-05 10:33:56.020 -0800
    OS Version:      iOS 6.0.1 (10A523)
    Report Version:  104
    
    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGTRAP)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Crashed Thread:  0
    
    Last Exception Backtrace:
    (0x33e2429e 0x3ab0697a 0x33e241c0 0x3a402c10 0x3a402ba6 0xee80c 0xe59ac 0x76a40 0xe3462 0xed374 0x9613e 0x96442 0x97364 0x39b475ec 0x39b347fc 0x39b34116 0x372b059e 0x372b01ce 0x33df916e 0x33df9112 0x33df7f94 0x33d6aeb8 0x33d6ad44 0x372af2e6 0x39b882f4 0xa9506 0x5d58c)
    
    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32d4d838 0x32d3d000 + 67640
    1   collapsibleD                    0x000f5b6e 0x5c000 + 629614
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x33e2457c 0x33d62000 + 796028
    3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3ab06a62 0x3aafe000 + 35426
    4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38cac078 0x38cab000 + 4216
    5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38cac110 0x38cab000 + 4368
    6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38cad594 0x38cab000 + 9620
    7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3ab069cc 0x3aafe000 + 35276
    8   CoreFoundation                  0x33d6af1c 0x33d62000 + 36636
    9   CoreFoundation                  0x33d6ad44 0x33d62000 + 36164
    10  GraphicsServices                0x372af2e6 0x372aa000 + 21222
    11  UIKit                           0x39b882f4 0x39b31000 + 357108
    12  collapsibleD                    0x000a9506 0x5c000 + 316678
    13  collapsibleD                    0x0005d58c 0x5c000 + 5516
    
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32d4ed98 0x32d3d000 + 73112
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa7ccf6 0x3aa76000 + 27894
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa7ca12 0x3aa76000 + 27154
    3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa7c8a0 0x3aa76000 + 26784
    
    Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32d3e648 0x32d3d000 + 5704
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3be5a974 0x3be52000 + 35188
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3be5a654 0x3be52000 + 34388
    
    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32d4ed98 0x32d3d000 + 73112
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa7ccf6 0x3aa76000 + 27894
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa7ca12 0x3aa76000 + 27154
    3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa7c8a0 0x3aa76000 + 26784
    
    Thread 4 name:  WebThread
    Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32d4e0fc 0x32d3d000 + 69884
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa77124 0x3aa76000 + 4388
    2   WebCore                         0x34cc9958 0x34cbd000 + 51544
    3   WebCore                         0x34cc988a 0x34cbd000 + 51338
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x33df96ca 0x33d62000 + 620234
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x33df79bc 0x33d62000 + 612796
    6   CoreFoundation                  0x33df7de8 0x33d62000 + 613864
    7   CoreFoundation                  0x33d6aeb8 0x33d62000 + 36536
    8   CoreFoundation                  0x33d6ad44 0x33d62000 + 36164
    9   WebCore                         0x34cc7a40 0x34cbd000 + 43584
    10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa8730e 0x3aa76000 + 70414
    11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa871d4 0x3aa76000 + 70100
    
    Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
    Thread 5:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32d3deb4 0x32d3d000 + 3764
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32d3e048 0x32d3d000 + 4168
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x33df9040 0x33d62000 + 618560
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x33df7d9e 0x33d62000 + 613790
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x33d6aeb8 0x33d62000 + 36536
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x33d6ad44 0x33d62000 + 36164
    6   Foundation                      0x3a3f4bc8 0x3a3c7000 + 187336
    7   Foundation                      0x3a478678 0x3a3c7000 + 726648
    8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa8730e 0x3aa76000 + 70414
    9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa871d4 0x3aa76000 + 70100
    
    Thread 6:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32d4ed98 0x32d3d000 + 73112
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa7ccf6 0x3aa76000 + 27894
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa7ca12 0x3aa76000 + 27154
    3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa7c8a0 0x3aa76000 + 26784
    
    Thread 7:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32d3deb4 0x32d3d000 + 3764
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32d3e048 0x32d3d000 + 4168
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x33df9040 0x33d62000 + 618560
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x33df7d9e 0x33d62000 + 613790
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x33d6aeb8 0x33d62000 + 36536
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x33d6ad44 0x33d62000 + 36164
    6   Foundation                      0x3a3cb78a 0x3a3c7000 + 18314
    7   Foundation                      0x3a46f058 0x3a3c7000 + 688216
    8   collapsibleD                    0x0010b010 0x5c000 + 716816
    9   Foundation                      0x3a478678 0x3a3c7000 + 726648
    10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa8730e 0x3aa76000 + 70414
    11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa871d4 0x3aa76000 + 70100
    
    Thread 8:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32d4ed98 0x32d3d000 + 73112
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa7ccf6 0x3aa76000 + 27894
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa7ca12 0x3aa76000 + 27154
    3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa7c8a0 0x3aa76000 + 26784
    
    Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
    Thread 9:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32d4e594 0x32d3d000 + 71060
    1   CoreFoundation                  0x33dfd1f2 0x33d62000 + 635378
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa8730e 0x3aa76000 + 70414
    3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa871d4 0x3aa76000 + 70100
    
    Thread 10 name:  AURemoteIO::IOThread
    Thread 10:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32d3deb4 0x32d3d000 + 3764
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32d3e048 0x32d3d000 + 4168
    2   AudioToolbox                    0x3b66e624 0x3b571000 + 1037860
    3   AudioToolbox                    0x3b67098c 0x3b571000 + 1046924
    4   AudioToolbox                    0x3b5ae8a2 0x3b571000 + 252066
    5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa8730e 0x3aa76000 + 70414
    6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa871d4 0x3aa76000 + 70100
    
    Thread 11 name:  AQClient
    Thread 11:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32d3deb4 0x32d3d000 + 3764
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32d3e048 0x32d3d000 + 4168
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x33df9040 0x33d62000 + 618560
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x33df7d9e 0x33d62000 + 613790
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x33d6aeb8 0x33d62000 + 36536
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x33d6ad44 0x33d62000 + 36164
    6   AudioToolbox                    0x3b5cd5b6 0x3b571000 + 378294
    7   AudioToolbox                    0x3b5ae8a2 0x3b571000 + 252066
    8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa8730e 0x3aa76000 + 70414
    9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa871d4 0x3aa76000 + 70100
    
    Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
        r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3c097fc8
        r4: 0xffffffff    r5: 0x0000001a      r6: 0x2fda4304      r7: 0x2fda49e0
        r8: 0x2fda4310    r9: 0x3d8f28a8     r10: 0x2fda4554     r11: 0x0000001a
        ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fda42e0      lr: 0x000f5b73      pc: 0x32d4d838
      cpsr: 0x000f0010
    
    Binary Images:
       0x5c000 -   0x193fff +collapsibleD armv7   /var/mobile/Applications/1812EF83-875B-49CD-9B97-46878ED60F8E/collapsibleD.app/collapsibleD
    0x2fee0000 - 0x2ff00fff  dyld armv7   /usr/lib/dyld
    0x32c7d000 - 0x32c81fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x32c83000 - 0x32c8ffff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x32d3d000 - 0x32d53fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x32fbd000 - 0x32fc3fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x32fc4000 - 0x32fecfff  PrintKit armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
    0x3300d000 - 0x3300efff  IOAccelerator armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
    0x33088000 - 0x330d3fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x330dc000 - 0x3318ffff  EventKit armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
    0x331aa000 - 0x332e4fff  AudioCodecs armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioCodecs
    0x332e5000 - 0x332effff  MailServices armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
    0x332f0000 - 0x332f7fff  OpenGLES armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
    0x33358000 - 0x33367fff  CoreVideo armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
    0x33368000 - 0x3336cfff  FTClientServices armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
    0x3336d000 - 0x333f2fff  MessageUI armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
    0x333f3000 - 0x33467fff  GameKitServices armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/GameKitServices
    0x33566000 - 0x33596fff  ContentIndex armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
    0x33597000 - 0x335b0fff  DictionaryServices armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
    0x335b1000 - 0x336a0fff  AVConference armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/Frameworks/AVConference.framework/AVConference
    0x336bf000 - 0x336c2fff  libmacho.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x336c3000 - 0x336ccfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
    0x336cd000 - 0x336defff  libvMisc.dylib armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
    0x336df000 - 0x3375cfff  HomeSharing armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
    0x33790000 - 0x33790fff  LegacyHandle armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/Frameworks/LegacyHandle.framework/LegacyHandle
    0x33995000 - 0x33995fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x33a39000 - 0x33b77fff  vImage armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
    0x33b78000 - 0x33b84fff  AccountSettings armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
    0x33b85000 - 0x33cd5fff  MusicLibrary armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
    0x33cf8000 - 0x33d18fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x33d36000 - 0x33d37fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x33d38000 - 0x33d4dfff  libmis.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
    0x33d62000 - 0x33e94fff  CoreFoundation armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
    0x33e95000 - 0x3411afff  MediaToolbox armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
    0x34130000 - 0x34192fff  CoreText armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
    0x341bc000 - 0x341c8fff  libz.1.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x341c9000 - 0x341cafff  CoreSurface armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
    0x341d0000 - 0x341d3fff  ActorKit armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
    0x342e5000 - 0x342eefff  MediaRemote armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
    0x34301000 - 0x3431cfff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
    0x34347000 - 0x3447ffff  CoreGraphics armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
    0x346d5000 - 0x34710fff  iCalendar armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
    0x34711000 - 0x34746fff  libcorecrypto.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x34747000 - 0x3479ffff  ManagedConfiguration armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
    0x347b3000 - 0x347b3fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x347b4000 - 0x34819fff  CoreMedia armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
    0x34868000 - 0x3489bfff  AppleAccount armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
    0x348f2000 - 0x34acafff  ImageIO armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
    0x34acb000 - 0x34ae7fff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x34af9000 - 0x34b00fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
    0x34b0d000 - 0x34b47fff  iTunesStore armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
    0x34bc9000 - 0x34bd0fff  MobileIcons armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
    0x34be5000 - 0x34be9fff  IOSurface armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
    0x34c82000 - 0x34ca6fff  Bom armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
    0x34cbd000 - 0x355ecfff  WebCore armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
    0x355ed000 - 0x355f0fff  libcache.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x35791000 - 0x357e7fff  CoreAudio armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
    0x3580c000 - 0x35824fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x35825000 - 0x35863fff  VideoToolbox armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
    0x358b2000 - 0x358effff  FTServices armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
    0x358f0000 - 0x359f9fff  IMGSGX543GLDriver armv7   /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX543GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX543GLDriver
    0x35bfe000 - 0x35c2bfff  MobileAsset armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
    0x35db9000 - 0x35dbefff  CommonUtilities armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
    0x35dc3000 - 0x35dcafff  liblockdown.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
    0x35ec9000 - 0x35edbfff  DataAccessExpress armv7
```

Comment: Are you using CoreData? I have seen this issue when the persistentStoreCoordinator fails to establish a persistentStore prior to reading from the context. Have you tried the Analyze feature in Xcode? (Product pulldown)

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log. On the computer you used to build the submission, drag the crash log onto the Organizer in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to run on Simulator.
2. Try to run on various real devices (including different versions aka iPad1, iPad2...)
3. Move initializing code from applicationDidFinishLaunch.
4. Review your entitements :)

Comment: one note: i don't know about now, but Apple did use sometimes Simulator one year ago during the review process

Comment: i have no entitlements.plist in the app, should i put one?

Comment: and i have a basic cocos2d project with no core data